# alpha_vantage API (python) not giving adjusted data

Tags: python, alpha-vantage

I`m trying to access the TSLA stock data but the data doesn't seem to have accounted for the split earlier this year. The Alpha_Vantage website claims that it will be set to adjust=true as default but this doesn't seem to be the case, I tried to specify adjust=true but this returned an unexpected keyword error.

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import pandas as pd
ts = TimeSeries(key= api_key, output_format='pandas'
data, meta_data = ts.get_daily(self.symbol, outputsize='full')
#tried ts.get_daily(self.symbol, outputsize='full') but still no luck. The image ive added shows the data in a graph. the crash, i believe is a split
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import pandas as pd
ts = TimeSeries(key= api_key, output_format='pandas')
data, meta_data = ts.get_daily_adjusted(self.symbol, outputsize='full')
```

[Here's](https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage/blob/develop/alpha_vantage/timeseries.py#L45) the method to get split adjusted closings.

[image: Graph Close vs Adjusted Close]

Comment: I have tried this and unfortunately, it has not made a difference. Im not sure if the issue is with the code or the alpha vantage data itself

Comment: @AlexReddock Just to be clear, what output/range are you expecting the call to return?

Comment: @AlexReddock I ask because I registered a key and the data around the split looks accurate to me: https://pastebin.com/dv6bEwP9

Comment: I`m not very experienced in finance. I was led to believe that the data adjusted to the split would look smoother?

Comment: @AlexReddock Looks like you graphed close instead of adjusted_close, I added a graph of both to my answer.